# get a button within a fragment from the activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, fragment

How would I do this? Or is it even possible get a `button` within a `fragment` from the `activity`?

I've tried many things e.g. trying to get the view or container of the fragment but no luck.

I am doing this as i have 27 `fragments` in an `activity` which all have a same `button`. Instead of doing a button listener on each fragment, i want to reduce my code greatly but just doing a loop in my `activity` going through each fragment and setting there button to activate the button listener (in the activity) if pressed.

Once i know how to get a `button` and set it to the button `listener`, I can easily do the loop bit my self.

Just finishing my first year for computer science and have been coding in java for a couple of years now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't loop or get reference to the button.

Simply make your activity implement OnClickListener and set it as click listeners for the buttons in all your fragments ..
In the fragment

```
yourBtn.setOnClickListener(((YourActivityType) getActivity()));
```

another solution without the implements keyword

is to have a public method in your activity, for example, `setButtonAction(Button btn)`

```
public void setButtonAction(Button btn) {
     btn.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
```

and declare myClickListener as variable in youractivity

Same idea without having your activity to implement clickLitener

Comment: ...Is there anyway to do this without the implement?

Comment: Changed it a little, I did:

((GameActivity)getActivity()).setButtonAction(view.findViewById(R.id.button1));

In the fragment and in the activity i did:

public void setButtonAction(View view) {
 Button btn = (Button) view;
        btn.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    }

Comment: you already looked up your button when passing it to setButtonAction, you don't have to use findViewById again inside the method